# read two keys values in C/C++

Tags: c++, events, keypress

How can I add two numbers when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is pressed? I am currently using the following code:

```
int key1=getch();
int key2;

while(key1==65)
{
    key2=getch();

    if( key1==65 && key2==37) // set whatever number you wish here :-), 27 =Esc
    {
        printf("A + left key");

    }   
    else
    {
        printf("other");
    }
}
```

But its not a proper method like I wanted. Can you help me out.

Answer (score 2):

To check if Crtl+A was pressed you can read input using `getch()` and compare obtained `char` to Crtl+A value which is equal to 1.

```
key = getch();
if(key == 1) {
    // do sth
}
```

If you want to wait for Crtl+A and then add this two numbers, simply wrap it inside `while` with same condition.

Comment: actually i am a newbie,couldn't get along,can you please help me with the code.thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly you want to do in your code?

Comment: i want to add two numbers when i press the key "s" and the "up" key. if i press "s" and "down" key it must subtract.